# Trouble with AJAX call on button in rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a StackOverflow clone and I've got two models at the moment, questions and answers. I have a working ajax call on my index page when users post a question to the homepage. However, I can't get my ajax call working on the individual question page when posting answers. Here is my answers controller code:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @new_answer = @question.answers.new answer_params
    respond_to do |format|
      if @new_answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
        format.js   {}
      else
        redirect_to @question
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

Here is my show.html.erb file:

```
<h1><%= @question.title %></h1>
<p><%= @question.content %></p>

<%= button_to "delete", question_path(@question), method: :delete, remote: true %>
<%= button_to "update", edit_question_path(@question), method: :get, remote: true %>

<h2>Answers:</h2>
<div class="answers">
  <% @answers.each do |answer| %>
    <%= render partial: "answers/answer", locals: {answer: answer} %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= form_for([@question, @question.answers.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>:
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :content %>:
  <%= f.text_area :content %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my _answer.html.erb partial file:

```
<div class="answer">
  <p><h3><%= answer.title %></h3> <%= answer.content %></p>
  <p>Upvotes: <%= answer.upvotes %> <%= button_to "upvote", upvote_question_answer_path(@question, answer), method: :patch, remote: true %></p>
  <p>Downvotes: <%= answer.downvotes %> <%= button_to "downvote", downvote_question_answer_path(@question, answer), method: :patch, remote: true %></p>
</div>
```

Finally, here is my create.js.erb file:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @answer) %>").appendTo(".answers");
```

When I submit a new answer on the show page, I receive the following error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/questions/4/answers 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I'm at a loss for what the issue might be. It seems to be an issue with my Answer#create controller, but any help would be appreciated! The new answer DOES appear when I refresh the page, if that's worth anything.

I really appreciate any help/feedback!

Comment: Generally, when I'm using AJAX, I at least render something in the format.js response e.g. `format.js { render @answer }`

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake, I realized my controller variable @new_answer was named differently than in my create.js.erb file, @answer. That solved the issue.